# Connecting an ASP.NET MVC application to MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql

How can I point my ASP.NET MVC application to a MySQL database?

Answer (score 3):

Once you [download the MySQL ADO.NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) it's a simple matter of referencing the assembly in your project and writing the queries, the same way you would do in any other application, nothing specific MVC:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM foo;";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
            // TODO: do something with the name ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a connection with the database :

First of all install the following packages from Nuget Manager

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

First Open Sql Server Management Studio, then click on the charger icon on the top in the left panel. You will see a popup. Enter the server name (remember it) and click ok.

Second, go to appSettings.json enter the following lines of code

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=Enter the Server name here;Database=Name anything you want;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"}
```

-Make sure to give a comma before it. And enter the name of the server that i asked you to remember.

inside your main project create a "data" folder and inside create a class by the name of "ApplicationDbContext.cs". Inside the class file paste the following code snippet which is just a kind of syntax

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

    }
//Make sure to import the entityframeworkcore in this file
```

Next, got to Program.cs and just above the "var app = builder.Build();" line paste the following code

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);
```

You might need to import the entity framework core in this file as well. Or simply add "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" in program.cs and ApplicationDbContext.cs file

Last step is to go to tools -> nuget package manager -> package manager console , in the console write the command `update-database` and click enter